# Recuperating Data From a WebService Using Alamofire Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, post, alamofire

How to recuperate data from the web service using the POST method with in swift 3 using Alamofire API , my xcode target version is ios 10.3.

This is an example of my web service data recuperation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfXxO.jpg

Comment: Please show code from your current attempts

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your question. Linking to external resources hurts our ability to answer your question. If you have questions please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i only download SwiftyJSON and alamofire and declare url.